# "print" versus "plot" in r

Tags: r, plot, png, rstudio

I want  to save my histogram as below.  When I run the following, the plot shows  up in Rstudio:

```
hist_L4 <- hist(L_4,breaks=10,main='histo')   
print(hist_L4)
```

When I try to save it like so, it just saves blank white images, which is not the same as the plots it printed in Rstudio.

```
hist_L4 <- hist(L_4,breaks=10,main='histo')    

png(file=paste0('path/name_of_png' , '.png' ))
print(hist_L4)
dev.off()
```

Why is it that I am getting blank white plots?  Thanks.

Comment: Why not pass the `hist` call directly. Alternatively use `plot(hist_L4)`

Comment: btw, are you sure the `print(hist_L4)` generates a plot, or is it the previous `hist_L4 <- hist(...` call that prints the plot?

Answer (score 2):

```
#Maybe simply this way?:
hist_L4 <- hist(L_4,breaks=10,main='histo')   
hist_L4

png(file=paste0('path/name_of_png' , '.png' ))
hist_L4
dev.off()
```

Comment: Does that work without a `plot` call... as in `plot(hist_L4)`